# Need help configuring BIND on Pfsense as an authoritative DNS Server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, pfsense, authoritative

For a few weeks now I've tried configuring BIND Server on my Pfsense Router as an authoritative DNS Server.

I own a domain bought from RoTLD, I've set my nameservers to my external static ip, and they have had enough time to propagate. Problem is that I have no idea how to configure the BIND package on Pfsense, and I may not open the firewall correctly for it. The errors I am getting are because the nameservers don't respond. I would like for the domain to respond with my external ip address as a starting point.

Any help would be highly appreciated, as I am unable to find anything really relevant to the Pfsense's way of using the BIND plugin. To my understanding I have to configure the plugin from the UI, because any changes written to the plugin's files will be re-written if I change anything in the UI.

This is my first post on Server Fault, and I don't know if I have given enough information on my problem...

Thank you, Andrew